# Infinite loop for unknown reasons

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

I am confused as to why this:

> regResponse.splice(i+1, 0, newString);

causes an infinite loop or something of the sort (page doesn't load). If I put it outside the if block, it isn't an infinite loop but then the logic of what I'm trying to do won't work. How is this happening? I can't see why it freezes the page.

If you put

> break;

directly after the regResponse.splice line, you'll see within console log the logic of what I'm doing is starting to come together as the title and the link itself are now separated for the first three items (until it reaches the if loop condition and breaks out of it).

var myString = "Accel World|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/accel-worldAh! My Goddess|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/ah-my-goddessAh! My Goddess TV|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/ah-my-goddess-tvAi Yori Aoshi|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/ai-yori-aoshiAir Gear|http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/air-gear"

```
myString = myString.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');

var reg = /[^|]+/g;
var regResponse = myString.match(reg);
console.log(regResponse);


for(i = 0; i < regResponse.length; i++) {
    if (regResponse[i].length > 20) {
       space = regResponse[i].indexOf(' ');
        var newString = regResponse[i].substring(space+1, regResponse[i].length);
        regResponse[i] = regResponse[i].slice(0, space);
        regResponse.splice(i+1, 0, newString);



    }

}
```

Comment: Your logic looks like complicated. Can you explain, what your code is trying to solve?

Comment: myString contains a Title and a link, seperated by |. I filter out the '|' then seperate lowercase letters when they next to capital letters. They should only be by each other when the link ends and there is a new title. I am then trying to parse it because the space lets me know how to find the end of the url link and the beginning of a new title. They can be then parsed into respective array elements and inserted into a table.

Comment: Hmmm, sample input and corresponding output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infinite loop is a result of extending the array (with [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)) as you're looping through it. Try performing your loop backwards to avoid this:

```
for (i = regResponse.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/cgop02f1/

Comment: How is splice doing that? If I am adding one to the array only when x condition is met, then it should only be added a set amount of times, and eventually the for loop will reach it because the if loop shouldn't be executing repeatedly.

Comment: `space = regResponse[i].indexOf(' ');` [which is -1 if no match is found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). So `newstring` is identical to the old string. You're just inserting the same string after itself over and over again. You could test for that instead: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/gttrLq2w/

Comment: That fixed another problem I was having, thanks. if the length is greater than 20, there should always be a match though. Which means it shouldn't insert the same string over and over because it will have found a space.

Comment: But how do you know any length greater than 20 will have a space? Don't make assumptions like that when writing code. It makes sense to test for the space instead. (Always assume your input might be corrupt, missing or malicious, and test that it's clean and properly formatted before processing it. This is true for any code.)

Comment: That's true. I'm wondering moreso where it went wrong, because I know I'm wrong. I just don't know where it went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your terminating condition depends on `regResponse.length`, but you are also adding elements to `regResponse`.

[Here is the documentation on Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Let's dive into your code:

```
for(i = 0; i < regResponse.length; i++) {
    if (regResponse[i].length > 20) {
       space = regResponse[i].indexOf(' ');
        var newString = regResponse[i].substring(space+1, regResponse[i].length);
        regResponse[i] = regResponse[i].slice(0, space);
        regResponse.splice(i+1, 0, newString);
    }
}
```

Let's see why this isn't terminating. We're going to assume where at a value of `i` in which the loop should end after, i.e. `i === regResponse.length - 1`. Now, the line `regResponse.splice(i+1, 0, newString)` will append a new element to the *end* of the regResponse array. Now `i === regResponse.length - 2`.

It looks like you had meant for `if (regResponse[i].length > 20)` to be your terminating statement. Try `if (regResponse[i].length < 20)` instead.